# Trying to get property of non-object on php artisan migrate command

Tags: php, laravel-4

After the following runs successfully **php artisan migrate:install**

I try to run the following to generate a users table  **php artisan migrate**
 from my migrations I get the following

> error [ErrorException] Trying to get property of non-object

The migrations looks like this :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('user', function(Blueprint $table)
    {   
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username', 128)->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->string('password')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->string('email')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->timestamps()->nullable->default(null);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the above code, the error seems to be here:

```
$table->timestamps()->nullable->default(null);
```

It should be:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

The method `timestamps` can't be chained with `nullable` property or `nullable()` method. The database fields that are created by `$table->timestamps()` are `created_at` and `updated_at` and by default their value is the timestamp `0000-00-00 00:00:00` and I don't think you can change that.

Also, if you do `nullable()` in other fields you don't need to add `default(null)` after that because the fields will have `NULL` as default value.

**UPDATE:** You'll also need to replace `Schema::table` with `Schema::create` if the migration is for creating a new table.

Comment: This did work out and also changing the schema from table to create helped

Comment: Oh! I hadn't noticed that you had `Schema::table` instead of `Schema::create`. My bad. I'll update the answer.